# How to expand facebook div to see full group name in left sidebar

Tags: html, css, facebook

Facebook page leaves margin on both left and ride side which truncates the group name showed on left sidebar as belows:

[image]

I am fed up with hovering over each name and find the exact group name as most of my groups have same prefix as shown. How can I expand to use left space to see full name always? I tried using the developer tool but looks FB UI is too encapsulated to do this trivially. Please help me with the steps to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This works at least when I try it. It can be used for example in a browser extension like Stylus ([Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/styl-us/), [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylus/clngdbkpkpeebahjckkjfobafhncgmne), [Opera](https://addons.opera.com/extensions/details/stylus/)). Tweak the margin-left value as needed.

```
#sideNav { margin-left: -2em !important; }
#sideNav .linkWrap { overflow: visible !important; }
```

Comment: Where to put this?

Comment: I cannot find #sideNav id

Comment: I was assuming you're using an extension like Stylus. How were you going to add the style?

Comment: I tried it in chrome developer tools to see if it works or not. If success, I would have added in tampermonkey. I tried stylus also after your comment but it didn't work. Did you write an exact solution or I need to replace sideNav with some exact name?

Comment: It works as it is when I try it in Stylus on Firefox. You can also try #left_nav_section_nodes instead of #sideNav.